# "Capybara::ElementNotFound: no button with value or id or text 'Follow' found" in Hartl Chapter 11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

I'm getting these Capybara errors (they're all pretty much the same) and don't know what I did wrong.

My specs are:

Ruby version: 1.9.2p320

Rails version: 3.2.13

Rspec: 2.11.1

Computer: Macbook Pro OS X Mountain Lion

**Errors**

```
8) User pages profile page follow/unfollow buttons following a user should increment the followed user count
     Failure/Error: click_button "Follow"
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       no button with value or id or text 'Follow' found
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:101:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:100:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  9) User pages profile page follow/unfollow buttons following a user should increment the other user's followers count
     Failure/Error: click_button "Follow"
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       no button with value or id or text 'Follow' found
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:107:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:106:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  10) User pages profile page follow/unfollow buttons following a user toggling the button 
     Failure/Error: before { click_button "Follow" }
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       no button with value or id or text 'Follow' found
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:112:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'

  11) User pages profile page follow/unfollow buttons unfollowing a user should decrement the followed user count
     Failure/Error: click_button "Unfollow"
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       no button with value or id or text 'Unfollow' found
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:125:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:124:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  12) User pages profile page follow/unfollow buttons unfollowing a user should decrement the other user's followers count
     Failure/Error: click_button "Unfollow"
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       no button with value or id or text 'Unfollow' found
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:131:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:130:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  13) User pages profile page follow/unfollow buttons unfollowing a user toggling the button 
     Failure/Error: before { click_button "Unfollow" }
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       no button with value or id or text 'Unfollow' found
     # (eval):2:in `click_button'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:136:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**user_pages_spec.rb**

```
describe "follow/unfollow buttons" do
      let(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      describe "following a user" do
        before { visit user_path(other_user) }

        it "should increment the followed user count" do
          expect do
            click_button "Follow"
          end.to change(user.followed_users, :count).by(1)
        end

        it "should increment the other user's followers count" do
          expect do
            click_button "Follow"
          end.to change(other_user.followers, :count).by(1)
        end

        describe "toggling the button" do
          before { click_button "Follow" }
          it { should have_selector('input', value: 'Unfollow') }
        end
      end

      describe "unfollowing a user" do
        before do
          user.follow!(other_user)
          visit user_path(other_user)
        end

        it "should decrement the followed user count" do
          expect do
            click_button "Unfollow"
          end.to change(user.followed_users, :count).by(-1)
        end

        it "should decrement the other user's followers count" do
          expect do
            click_button "Unfollow"
          end.to change(other_user.followers, :count).by(-1)
        end

        describe "toggling the button" do
          before { click_button "Unfollow" }
          it { should have_selector('input', value: 'Follow') }
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message reports, you don't have a button with the text or ID "Follow". I've seen this happen in cases where an anchor pretending to be a button in fact *did* exist with the caption "Follow", but Capybara wants to see an actual *button* with that text.

Comment: Okay, can you help me make the necessary changes? Is there any other files I can upload?

Comment: @user2469211 post your template.